# SQL and PHP order by with count

Tags: php, sql

I have this following SQL statement / PHP recordset;

```
$sql_result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reports GROUP BY post DESC", $db);
while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)) {
    echo "post $rs[post] has $rs[num] reports<br>";
    }
```

The num field doesn't exist, but I want it to display how many are in that group. I assume it uses a COUNT in the SQL but not sure where.

Any advice?

Comment: Sure, MySQL's aggregate `COUNT()` function will do that.

Comment: select post, count(post) from reports group by post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the aggregate `COUNT(*)` function along with `GROUP BY` to get per-group counts. And `DESC` can only be used along with `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT post, COUNT(*) AS num
FROM reports
GROUP BY post
ORDER BY num DESC
```